# HTML and CSS for gallery image border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want create this type gallery. I have multiple images in it. So when I hover on it then images should changes automatically.
Now I'm facing one issue i.e. How to add two borders like this using css or any other style-sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some `box-shadow` together. The first one is gray. The second one is white as a border with a one-pixel movement than the previous.

```css
body{
background:#efefef;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding:10px;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 0 gray,6px -6px 0 white,11px -11px 0 lightgray,12px -12px 0 white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with three elements. One element is the image itself, and it has a tiny `1px` white border. Then there are two elements behind the image that have grey background and also white border.

Look at this [example](https://codepen.io/rastiq/pen/bGLZbvm), pretty much the same, just change the `div` with class `image` for an actual `img` element and invert the positioning and you are ready to go.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  position: absolute;
}

.first {
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #777;
}

.second {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
background-color:black;
}
.imageContainer{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:100px;
top:200px;
left:200px;
padding:50px;
background: url("https://media.cntraveller.com/photos/611bf0b8f6bd8f17556db5e4/1:1/w_2000,h_2000,c_limit/gettyimages-1146431497.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.divOne{
position:absolute;
border-top:3px solid grey;
border-right:3px solid grey;

width:100%;
height:100%;
top:-6px;
left:6px;
z-index:-1;
}

.divTwo{
position:absolute;
border-top:3px solid grey;
border-right:3px solid grey;

width:100%;
height:100%;
top:-10px;
left:10px;
z-index:-1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="imageContainer">

<div class="divOne"></div>
<div class="divTwo"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```